# Is UB assigning a local literal string to a global scope variable?

Tags: c++, c++14, undefined-behavior

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

const char* out;

void f() {
    const char* in = "foo";
    out = in;
}

int main(){
    f();
    std::cout << out;
}
```

I'd like to know whether using `out` in `std::cout << out;` is undefined behavior.

In `const char* in = "foo";`, the literal `"foo"` is a object? I mean, when the expression is evaluated, an object is created to represent `"foo"`? If not, the `in` pointer points to the program's image? How lifetime works here for `"foo"` and `in`?

Comment: FWIW: If this _was_ UB, returning any pointer of/to a string literal "local to" the function would be UB for the same reason.